# Update billing account on google cloud project programmatically?

Tags: ruby, api, google-cloud-platform

I have a large number of projects in my organization that I want to shift the billing account for. The Ruby API has [Google::Apis::CloudbillingV1::ProjectBillingInfo](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/CloudbillingV1/ProjectBillingInfo) which contains an [update!](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/CloudbillingV1/ProjectBillingInfo#update!-instance_method) method that should let me do this.

I'm missing a step though. My code looks like this:

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/cloudbilling_v1'

service = Google::Apis::CloudbillingV1::CloudbillingService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

FROM_BA = 'billingAccounts/123456'
TO_BA   = 'billingAccounts/789012'

puts "Changing billing account on projects:"
service.list_billing_account_projects(FROM_BA).project_billing_info.each do |p|
  puts "\t#{p.name} (#{p.project_id}): #{p.billing_account_name} --> #{TO_BA}"
  p.update!(billing_account_name: TO_BA)
end
```

The loop does find and list all the projects in the `FROM_BA` billing account. And I know `update!` is being called. But the changes aren't persisted to the projects in the account. I suspect I'm missing a step here. A commit call? I can't seem to find any examples and the docs aren't helpful here.

Anyone know how to persist the `update!` changes upstream to the actual projects in the account?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [update_project_billing_info method](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/cloudbilling_v1/service.rb#L245) on the `CloudBillingService` instance to commit the changes to the `ProjectBillingInfo` object.

The full snippet, that works, now looks like this:

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/cloudbilling_v1'

service = Google::Apis::CloudbillingV1::CloudbillingService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

FROM_BA = 'billingAccounts/123456'
TO_BA   = 'billingAccounts/789012'

puts "Changing billing account on projects:"
service.list_billing_account_projects(FROM_BA).project_billing_info.each do |p|
  project = p.name.split('/')[0..1].join('/')
  puts "\t#{project} (#{p.project_id}): #{p.billing_account_name} --> #{TO_BA}"
  p.update!(billing_account_name: TO_BA)
  service.update_project_billing_info(project, p) 
end
```

I see the billing info changes propagated to the web UI now.